# Why is my function is not able to find a phone number in the given string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I was writing some code that would  find a phone number, if any in a given string. Here’s the code:

```
def k(num):

 import sys
 def f():
   print('NO')
   sys.exit()


 if (num[0:2]).isdecimal() and (num[4:6]).isdecimal() and (num[8:11]).isdecimal():
   pass
 else:
   f()

 if num[3]=='-' and num[7]=='-' :
   print('The number that I found is' + ' ' + str(num))
 else:
     f()


inpt1=input('please enter the string.')
inpt2=inpt1.split()

for i in inpt2:
  if len(i)==12:
    k(i)
  else:
    pass
```

The number should be of the format `xxx-xxx-xxxx`.

I then copied some text from Wikipedia “**These compact structures guide the interactions between DNA and other proteins, helping control which parts of the DNA are transcribed.DNA was first isolated by Friedrich Miescher in 1869. Its molecular structure was first identified by James Watson and Francis 123-333-1111 Crick at the Cavendish Laboratory within the University of Cambridge**”  and inserted a number (123-333-1111) somewhere in the middle of the text but the program is just returning `NO` instead of returning that number. Why is this happening?

Also, if I put in some simple input like:
`My name is Harry Potter. My number is 222-333-1111`
Then the code works perfectly fine!

EDIT: The code that would work is :

```
def k(num):

 while True:
  if (num[0:2]).isdecimal() and (num[4:6]).isdecimal() and (num[8:11]).isdecimal():
    pass
  else:
    break


  if num[3]=='-' and num[7]=='-' :
    print('The number that I found is' + ' ' + str(num))
    break
  else:
     break

inpt1=input('please enter the string.')
inpt2=inpt1.split()

for i in inpt2:
  if len(i)==12:
    k(i)
  else:
    pass
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I executed your code and after a run, I found that the problem is that in the input text, the word interactions is also of 12 characters. So initially the criterion to enter the function is met but inside the function it fails the first criterion as its a word and it prints NO and the statement `sys.exit()` is executed therefore the other words are never checked.Hope this helps.

Comment: Great answer! Keep it up

Comment: Thanks for the amazing answer! If have edited my question. Do you think there is any scope of improvement in my new code?

Comment: Thank you Aaryan Dewan. I think the best way would be to check the number format using regex as stated by @Ahsanul Haque. But as per your requirement I guess your edit is ok.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `re` to easily achieve the desired result.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\d{3}\-\d{3}\-\d{4}', 'My name is Harry Potter. My number is 222-333-1111')
['222-333-1111']
>>> tmp = 'These compact structures guide the interactions between DNA and other proteins, helping control which parts of the DNA are transcribed.DNA was first isolated by Friedrich Miescher in 1869. Its molecular structure was first identified by James Watson and Francis 123-333-1111 Crick at the Cavendish Laboratory within the University of Cambridge'
>>> re.findall(r'\d{3}\-\d{3}\-\d{4}', tmp)
['123-333-1111']
```

This `\d{3}\-\d{3}\-\d{4}` part basically implies that we need to find a  pattern which starts  with 3 digit, then a `-`, then 3 digit, then a `-`, and finally another 4 digit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you please incorporate this modification in my code and modify your answer so that it becomes more easy for me to read as I am unable to understand where should I use your modification in my code?

Comment: @Ron.W, actually `regular expression` is a preferable way for finding specific pattern out of a string. In python, the `re` module provides the facility of regular expression. My answer is an alternative solution to your attempt, not as a modification of your solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for telling me about `re` module. Could you also please tell me why isn’t my code working? Where’s the loophole?